# Building dynamic queries which contains between clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to generate dynamic queries in my program based on search criteria. I am commonly using the following method. I need to add a between clause to this.

```
$firstname = 'AAA';
$lastname = 'BBB';
$fromdate = '2015-01-01';
$todate = '2015-01-31';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$cond = array();
$params = array();
if (!empty($firstname)) {
    $cond[] = "firstname = ?";
    $params[] = $firstname;
}
if (!empty($lastname)) {
    $cond[] = "lastname = ?";
    $params[] = $lastname;
}
if (!empty($fromdate) && !empty($todate)) {
    // Here I need to add a between $fromdate AND $todate
}
if (count($cond)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Is there a way to add between clause to this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the clause before executing.

```
if (count($cond)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
}
if (!empty($fromdate) && !empty($todate)) {
    $query .= ' col_field BETWEEN ? AND ?';
    $params[]= $fromdate;
    $params[]= $todate;
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```